# Database storage on Google drive - android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm developing an app to make list for the shopping. Up to now, these lists were  stored into databases. But now I want to sync these databases between several devices. For this, I have chosen the way to stored these databases on a document provider like Google Drive.

In this way, I'm following this tutorial [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Storage_Access_Framework_Example). But I cannot figure out why I'm stuck on the following error after I run the app on my real device:

```
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5096)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    ... 11 more
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=text/plain (has extras) }
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3352)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    at com.example.storagedemo.StorageDemoActivity.newFile(StorageDemoActivity.java:51)
10-21 18:21:50.858: E/AndroidRuntime(16704):    ... 14 more
```

This is my activity : StorageDemoActivity.java

```
public class StorageDemoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static EditText textView;

    private static final int CREATE_REQUEST_CODE = 40;
    private static final int OPEN_REQUEST_CODE = 41;
    private static final int SAVE_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_storage_demo);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fileText);
    }

    public void newFile(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "newfile.txt");

        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent resultData) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (requestCode == CREATE_REQUEST_CODE)
            {   
                    if (resultData != null) {
                            textView.setText("");
                    }
            }

            }
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_storage_demo, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my FragmentLayout : fragment_storage_demo

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.storagedemo.StorageDemoActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:text="@string/new_string" 
        android:onClick="newFile"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="openFile"
        android:text="@string/open_string" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="saveFile"
        android:text="@string/save_string" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fileText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

At last, this is my Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.storagedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.storagedemo.StorageDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks a lot for people who will help me!

Comment: It would appear that you either don't have an app capable of handling this task installed, or haven't specified what you want in a way that exactly matches the way the thing you are hoping will handle it specifies what it can handle.

Comment: I don't know, I'm perfectly following the tuto then it shouldn't have any matter. However, I wonder how my app can know my Google drive because there is nowhere in the code which gives information about it. Thanks for your comment @Chris Stratton.

Comment: If your code came directly from a tutorial, then it's likely you don't have a dependency installed.  Is the Google Drive app installed on your device?

Comment: Yes I thought it was the issue, but I have checked and I have Google Drive app. I have restarted my app after opening Google Drive but same error message...

Comment: Are you running your app on Android 4.4 (KitKat) or higher?

Comment: I'm running the app on Android 4.2.2, do you think this is the problem?

Comment: @KevHV : The Storage Access Framework was introduced in Android v4.4 so you need to be testing on a device or emulator running KitKat.. I don't know if they've added the SAF stuff to one of the compatibility libraries but if they have you may be able to use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Squonk, I can stop my Headhache! So I'm coming back once again toward dropbox and I hope to succeed what I need.

Comment: @KevHV : I've just looked at the Support Library revisions and there's no mention of any SAF stuff. Thinking about it, it's likely to only be available in runtime libraries anyway and may only ever available on v4.4 devices or later.

Comment: Thank you for your enquiry @Squonk. If I understand, do you mean that I should look for libraries allowing me to send data on Google Drive whatever my Android version? (Sorry, I'm a newbie)

Comment: @KevHV : To be honest I'm not sure as it's not something I've done. I suggest you search as much as possible for libraries related to cloud storage in general.

Comment: @Squonk All right, if I find out something I will to post it here!